# Counting TAB/SPACES before a particular line

Tags: text-processing, xml

I have a requirement in which I need to identify a field in a file, If found than I will have to add a new line and add some text. But I want to count the number of SPACES before the word found so that I can add a new line after that amount of spaces plus 2 additional spaces.
e.g.

input file:

```
  <tt:abcdef>

  .

  .

  .
  
  </tt:abcdef>
```

In the above input file I have 2 SPACES before `<tt:abcdef>`, I want to count those spaces and then write a new line like below

Expected Output file:

```
  <tt:abcdef>

     <tt:newvar>

  .

  .

  .
  
  </tt:abcdef>
```

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output.

Comment: XML documents don't usually care about the amount of whitespace between nodes. The spacing between nodes doesn't impact the parsing of the document and usually does not carry any information. Please show an example where the number of whitespace matters (for example, you may want to modify the _value_ (text) in a node). Indentation is not essential to the information in the document and could be done automatically in post-processing for presentational purposes (e.g. with `xmlstarlet fo`).

Comment: We have a list of JSP that contains a word like <tt:acbdef>. Since the occurrence of this field can be find in multiple JSPs we need to write a shell script so that wherever the field <tt:abcdef> is found we need to add a new line in the JSP. The new line added should be in such a way that it maintains the indentation of the JSP. So the new JSP would look like <tt:abcdef> <tt:newtext>.

Comment: Just to add we don't have xmlstarlet installed in our systems so not possible to use it.

Comment: As all others suggest, do not worry about indentation. I would insert the content and then call `xmllint --format input.xml > output.xml`.

Comment: If you haven't got `xmlstarlet` (or `xmllint`) installed, install it. Or make an application through your Change Board to have it installed on your behalf. You shouldn't be trying to edit XML documents without proper tools

Comment: Also, if you insist on doing this, you need to explain to us what you need. You "have 2 SPACES before `<tt:abcdef>`". OK, so what should we add on the new line? 4 spaces? 8 spaces? A tab? What if you have 2 tabs, should we add 4 tabs? Also, you say you cannot install software. OK, but then what operating system are you using? We need to know this to know what tools are likely to be available to you.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is as simple and regular as you show and you don't have and can't install xmlstarlet, etc. then using any awk in any shell on every Unix box you can do:

```
$ awk '{print} sub(/<tt:abcdef>/,"  "){print $0 "<tt:newvar>"}' file
  <tt:abcdef>
    <tt:newvar>

  .

  .

  .

  </tt:abcdef>
```

The above doesn't count spaces, it just reuses whatever leading spaces exist on the matched line. It's not intended to be robust, just to change the input you provided to the output you provided. if you need more than that then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output and a better explanation of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -pe 's/^  (\s+) \<tt\:abcdef\> /{$/}\n$0  <tt:newvar>/;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -pe 's[^  (\s+) \<tt\:abcdef\> ]="{$/}\n$0  <tt:newvar>";'
```

Sample Input:

```
  <tt:abcdef>
  .
  .
  .
  </tt:abcdef>
```

Sample Output:

```
  <tt:abcdef>
    <tt:newvar>
  .
  .
  .
  </tt:abcdef>
```

Above are answers coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Briefly, the `-pe` autoprinting linewise flags are used to implement the traditional `s///` substitution idiom (written in the second example as `s[…]="…"`.

Because you ask for the recognition sequence `^  (\s+) \<tt\:abcdef\>` to be reproduced entirely in your output, the match variable `$/` is included in the right (substitution) half of the `s///` operator. The number of `(\s+)` spaces is captured into `$0` and added back into the substitution. Note, the solutions above display `$/` as `{$/}`, i.e. within a code block, however in practice (for your requirements), the curly braces are unnecessary.

Above is the simplest solution. In fact you may see unmatched tags in messy text files so you may indeed have to think about detecting tag-pairs (requiring a more complex solution).

https://raku.org